# Cassandra access algorithm (and cost) of clustering key

Tags: cassandra

In most of the documentation about Cassandra I read that the tables can be thought as:

```
Map<PrimaryKey, SortedMap<ClusteringKey>>
```

So I expect the access by PrimaryKey to be something like O(log n).
But what about the ClustringKey (obviously when a PrimaryKey is also specified in the query)?

I mean: searching for

```
where primarykey=someval and clusteringkey=some_clustering_val
```

would be something like O(log n)+O(log n) no matter if the "anotherval" value is at the end or at the beginning of the row based on the clusteringkey ordering?

I can't find proper documentation on how the data is actually fetched from the row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The read path is described, for example, in the [DSE's Architecture guide](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/dse-arch/datastax_enterprise/dbInternals/dbIntAboutReads.html).

There are multiple things here that affect data access cost (only listing some of them):

- Partition is often split between multiple SSTables - when you performed updates, insertion of different clustering keys, etc.  It will become the structure as you described only when compaction process moves data into single SSTable
- Data is stored in compressed form - you'll need to decompress the whole data block to access to particular clustering column's data

Comment: thank you for the link; but in case of compressed form, what is the access pattern for the decompressed data? Is it some kind of binary tree access, or sequential?

Comment: There is an index file for every SSTable that maps row keys into location in file. (but exact format depends on version). You may look into this presentation: https://www.slideshare.net/DataStax/what-is-in-all-of-those-sstable-files-not-just-the-data-one-but-all-the-rest-too-john-schulz-the-pythian-group-cassandra-summit-2016 & the links at the end of it.